# Error: Failed to execute 'toBlob' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet, html2canvas

I have a map that I want to export it as Png. I'm using `leaflet` for initializing map and `Leaflet.BigImage` and `html2canvas` for capturing the image. my problem is that sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

I tried many ways. my server side Api has `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and in my code I allowed CORS.

```
html2canvas(element, {
        useCORS: true,
        allowTaint: true,
      }).then(function (canvas) {
        canvas.toBlob(function (blob) { //----> Error here!
          var a = document.createElement("a");
          document.body.appendChild(a);
          a.style = "display: none";

          var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          a.href = url;
          a.download = "Export-Map.png";
          a.click();
          window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
          controlPanel.innerHTML = label;
          span.disabled = false;
          isLock = false;
        });
      });
```

and i set `img.crossOrigin="anonymous"` for my Image.
I don't know why sometimes it doesn't work.
I tried every other ways that duplicate questions said.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and provide a reproducible example - if there's just one non-CORS item in your map container (i.e. other than the `BigImage`, but the background tiles or other elements), the whole canvas will be tainted.

Comment: @IvanSanchez in that case it should not work at all. why does it work sometimes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was I had 2 maps in different tabs and the other map was tainting the canvas somehow. I solved the problem by using `*ngIf` so only one map works at the time. before that I was using `hidden`.